# Don't use SafeArea inset on iPhone X for first UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, iphone-x

I have a `UITableView` and the first row is used as a sort of header cell with a full bleed background image and other elements. For this cell I do NOT want to use the `SafeArea` and I want the `UIView` to expand all the way to the edge of the screen. Currently I get this:

[image]

I have tried to set this manually for the cell:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {

    headerCell.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = NO;
    headerCell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 10, 0);
    UIEdgeInsets i = headerCell.layoutMargins;
    NSLog(@"Left: %f", i.left);
}
```

Sadly this doesn't work.

Here is a mockup of what it should look like, with the first cell contents NOT being affected by the safe area:

[image]

Is there any way to do what I am wanting just for the first cell?

Comment: Can you not use a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` rather than a `UITableViewCell`? Apple talks about this issue with header views in this video starting at 8 minutes in: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/201

Comment: I think you are going to have to somewhat fake it by making the UITableView stretch the full width (i.e. ignoring the safe area) and then to inset the UITableViewCells back for everything except the first one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that I needed to uncheck the `Content View Insets To Safe Area` checkbox that is on the UITableView.

[image]

Doing this fixed the issue!

Comment: My understanding is that this changes the contentInsets for all the cells in the tableView. How did you manage to change the insets only on the first tableViewCell ?

Answer (score 11):

Marking the "**Content insets**" under Size Inspector to "**Never**" worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In code, it could be accomplished by

```swift
        tableView.insetsContentViewsToSafeArea = false
```

Comment: You save my day dude! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just go to the tableview Size inspector and look for the **Content Insets** by default it will be set to Automatic change that to **Never** as shown like in the image below
[image]